# localstorage не очищается

Tags: javascript

никак не очищается localstorage всегда хранит ключ и значение, хотя хром показывает что localstorage пуст, вывожу консоле.лог

Storage {length: 0}
userself : "ent"
length : 1
**proto** : Storage

итак пробовал

```
  localStorage.removeItem("userself");
  console.log(localStorage);
```

и так тоже

```
localStorage.clear();
console.log(localStorage);
```

**upd**
весь код

```
  $(function() {

    localStorage.removeItem("userself");
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userself'));
    console.log(localStorage);

    if (localStorage.userself = "priv") {
      $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
      $("a.ms_a.ms_priv").addClass('active');
    }

    if (localStorage.userself = "ent") {
      $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
      $("a.ms_a.ms_ent").addClass('active');
    }

    $("a.ms_a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        dataUserself = $(this).attr('data-userself');
        $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        localStorage.userself = dataUserself;
    });

  });
```

картинка консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что выводит после очистки `console.log(localStorage.getItem('userself'))`?

Comment: выводит null, но после простой консоле лог дает Storage {length: 0} userself : "ent" length : 1 proto : Storage

Comment: и дальнейший код, который юзает этот ключ опять же его получает

Comment: добавил весь код и картинку консоли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неверно используете `localStorage`.

```
$(function() {

  localStorage.removeItem("userself");
  localStorage.clear();
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('userself'));
  console.log(localStorage);

  if (localStorage.getItem('userself') == "priv") {
    $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
    $("a.ms_a.ms_priv").addClass('active');
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('userself') == "ent") {
    $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
    $("a.ms_a.ms_ent").addClass('active');
  }

  $("a.ms_a").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      dataUserself = $(this).attr('data-userself');
      $('a.ms_a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      localStorage.setItem('userself', dataUserself);
  });

});
```

Comment: На MDN [говорится](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API): _"You can access these values like an object, or with the Storage.getItem() and Storage.setItem() methods"_ - доступ через свойство корректен, хотя и не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (localStorage.userself = "priv") {
> ```

А вот не надо так делать. Тут ошибка `=` вместо `==` или `===`.

Comment: (фэйспалм), как солнце из-за туч

Comment: Тут ошибка еще в получении значении способом `localStorage.userself`. Это получение метода `userself`, а не значение ключа.

Comment: но вот ключ то откуда? почему не дохнет

Comment: Так информация в `localStorage` храниться не будет и после обновления оно потеряется.

Comment: mix, а как правильно? я только сегодня взялся за это

Comment: @cache0 написал правильный ответ.

Comment: @mix, в Хроме код `localStorage.setItem("someMyItem", 42); localStorage.someMyItem` выводит `"42"`, хотя при первом взгляде на вопрос я тоже подумал, что так читать нельзя. А после проверки убрал фразу _"к тому же"_ перед _"тут ошибка"_ :)

Comment: @Qwertiy хром это может позволить, но в других браузерах(не считая старых), такое может не пройти. Поэтому я сторонник того, чтобы делать все по документации

Comment: @mix, на MDN [говорится](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API): _"You can access these values like an object, or with the Storage.getItem() and Storage.setItem() methods"_ - доступ через свойство корректен, хотя и не рекомендуется.

Comment: @cache0, через свойство тоже можно, хотя и не рекомендуется.

Comment: Спасибо Вам всем! Чаще буду сюда заходить